# Не запускается приложение на Android 4.2

Tags: android, firebase

Ребята,на версиях Api22 и ниже выбивает ошибку ниже.
Загуглив,понял что проблема с MultiDex. Вроде бы всё добавил, что идёт по инструкции,но ничего не поменялось.Выручайте.

Ошибка:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider" on path: /data/app/by.ittech.test_chat-2.apk
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4822)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4432)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4372)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:141)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1294)
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
                                                     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider" on path: /data/app/by.ittech.test_chat-2.apk
                                                     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
                                                     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
                                                     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4807)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4432) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4372) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:141) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1294) 
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041) 
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="by.ittech.test_chat">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".BeginSign">
            <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
            >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".SignIn">
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

build:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "by.ittech.test_chat"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:1.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.github.siyamed:android-shape-imageview:0.9.+@aar'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}














apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Activity:

```
package by.ittech.test_chat;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.multidex.MultiDex;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;

import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;

public class BeginSign extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context context) {
        super.attachBaseContext(context);
        MultiDex.install(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_begin_sign);
        findViewById(R.id.begin_input).setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        /*Если вход уже выполнен,пользователь переходит сразу в главное окно*/
        if(mAuth.getCurrentUser() != null){
            //that means user is already logged in
            //so close this activity
            finish();
            //and open profile activity
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class));
        }
        /*Если пользователь не авторизован*/
        else{
            finish();
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SignIn.class));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Неверная у вас инструкция. Вот правильная https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html В активити уже поздно инициализировать MutilDex, это нужно делать в Application.

Comment: @YuraIvanov так объясните,что я делал не так? Я вижу,что там единственное отличие это наследование MultiDex

Comment: Вас скорее всего достаточно добавить в манифесте строчку: `<application android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication" >         ...</application>`

Comment: @YuraIvanov вроде заработало,но теперь просит обновить Google Play services. Посмотрел в эмуляторе.Версия 9.2+,попытался поменять версию в builde на более раннюю,выбивает ошибку,мол обновитесь до 10.2.0(которая у меня и стояла)